# Visual Studio - Mylyn Equalivent

Tags: visual-studio-2012, bug-tracking, mylyn

This has been asked before on stackoverflow but the answers were very unsatisfying.

I am looking for a tasked based plugin to Visual Studio that operates much in the same way as Mylyn does for Eclipse.  I am interested in something that a team could use to manage issues and requests from within VS, and it would be awesome if that could integrate with Eclipse (using something like bugzilla)

VS2012.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What's wrong with Team Foundation Server?

Comment: @RowlandShaw: Mylyn is a little bit different - it's a front-end that provides a different view of your data; the data is still stored in your version control and issue tracking backends (which may be Team Foundation Server.)